# Override Style in Jade?

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to override a bootstrap class's padding in jade like so:

`a.navbar-brand(href='#', style={padding:'0px'})`

But the resulting HTML ends up like so:

`&lt;a href="#" style="[object Object]" class="navbar-brand"&gt;`

Looking at the docs they have an example under "Style Attributes" that is almost identical, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work. http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your version of jade. With 1.4, I get your "[object Object]" output, but with 1.8 I get the desired CSS. Not sure exactly when this feature appears but you should be OK if you use the current latest version.

Comment: Thanks I was 1.6 after updating to 1.8 problem solved.